# Ender 3 first print some area is smooth but some is rough?

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3

Please check following image, Dog looks smooth from left side but its rough from right side , similar on back too.

What could have caused this ?

Can it be due to moisture due to Air Conditioner in my room ?
[image: dog pic]

Comment: please fill in the [] in the template I added and then remove the leading <. This will turn it visible and allow much better answers.

Comment: We need to know your sliver and its settings

Comment: @RobertoLoGiacco That's the dog that prints from a gcode file on the sd card that comes with the printer. Mr Coder, I don't think it's due to moisture from the air conditioner since air conditioners reduce humidity. But the uneven cool air draft could affect the print. Try printing with the AC off if you can or try covering the printer with something as simple as a cardboard box to see if anything changes. That print is affected so much just on one side that it looks like a draft is the issue.

Comment: @T.M.: It is the model, but it's not clear to me if it's the shipped gcode or resliced. I recall mine having larger brim and supports. The image looks more like a raft.

Comment: @R.. I suppose it’s possible it’s resliced but mine that came with my CR-10 I bought recently had a raft.

Comment: @RobertoLoGiacco what is silver , as for the settings I used everything defaults of ender3 , gcode of this model came inside sd card with ender3

Comment: @MrCoder that is a typo, I meant to write slicer, but you answered already

Comment: If you print with the model rotated, does the defect area move with the model, or remain oriented to the print head?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was making following mistakes

a) X-axis belt needed a tightening
( I calibrated all X,Y,Z and they were perfect)

b) There was under extrusion .
    ( I had to increase number of steps per mm for extruder motor and store the setting)

XYZ calibration cube was really helpful in debugging the problems .

Comment: Do you have a link to the XYZ calibration cube you used? Also what procedure did you use to determine if the belt was tight enough?

Comment: Calibration cube : https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1278865, tight the belt as much you can without stretching it .

Answer (score -2):

It is most likely caused by inadequate part-cooling due to poor air-flow. Fit a [better] part cooling fan. There are plenty of designs on Thingiverse.

You may also be able to resolve the issue by adjusting the printing temperature, but the easiest solution is to install a good part-cooling fan.

Comment: I think this is unlikely. I experimented with custom fan ducts and found they introduced warping problems due to intensity of air flow in small points. The stock duct works quite well.

Comment: The ender3 has the cooler mounted on the right side of the heater.

Comment: Yes. The problem could be *related* to cooling, but that doesn't mean "aftermarket fan or duct" is the solution, and I'd really caution anyone just starting *against* jumping to trying things like that. It sounds more likely that the hotend temp is marginal for the material and failing to extrude properly depending on air flow.

Comment: Stop telling people every issue is a cooling issue. Most of the time they haven't even bothered to tension their belts properly let alone calibrate their printer. Saying it's "Most likely cooling" is premature and bad advice.